# Wordpress - Add class to subcategories in loop

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to fix a plugin that lists post categories in relation to a restaurant menu. I need to somehow add a class to all subcategories. right now it lists categories and subcategories alike. The loop is here

```
<ul>

<?php
$menu_types = get_terms( 'rm-menu-type');

//list tabs first
$tab_count = 1; 
foreach ( $menu_types as $menu_type ) {
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'rm-menu-entry',
'nopaging'  => true,
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'rm-menu-type',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => $menu_type 
)
)
);


?>
<li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $tab_count;?>"><?php echo $menu_type->name; ?></a></li>
<?php 
$tab_count++;
} 
?>
</ul>
```

What i am looking for is a way to visually represent what is main, and what is subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try? With Version 3.0 the taxonomy parameter was added to enable wp_list_categories()
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy

Comment: Hello Garry, thank you for taking the time to answer. My problem is that i dont know how to transfer that to my current issue. I am (the plugin is) using a foreach loop to have jquery tabs functionality built in. Thats why its naming the tabs tabs-1, tabs-2 etc. I dont see how i could do that with the wp-list-categories function.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to fix the plugin was simply to much hassle, and i decided to redo the functionality with a custom post type and the bootstrap tabs. Works alot better, and will be a lot easier to scale in the future.